# VBA hightlight textboxes with a few lines

Tags: vba, textbox, highlight

i'am wondering if there's a way to use a few lines of code to hightlight all textboxes in the form.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
TextBox1.SelStart = 0
TextBox1.SelLength = Len(TextBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

This line above only works for textbox1 but i have a few hundred textboxes.I could copy this line a few hundred times an change the number of the textbox. But i've there is a way to speed this up and use less code please let me know!

Comment: what do you mean by highlight?

Comment: if you click on the textbox the text is selected

Comment: You have *a few hundred textboxes*?? If you've implemented a "grid" with textboxes, you're abusing them and could be using a worksheet instead.

Comment: yeah its like a liqour list of our disco. and for each bar we've 37 different sorts of drinks. and i want to use a user form to count the sellings from the refrigerator of each bar. so i also have a worksheet but use the userform to easy implement the counts.

Comment: I don't see the justification for using a hundred textboxes. What "counts" are easier to implement? Besides, you can't (or perhaps you can hack it, but you shouldn't) select the text in several textboxes at once.